# How to fix update error Code 0x8024a105 on Windows 10 to update OS

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, updates

I bought Minecraft windows 10 on Microsoft store but it requires a higher version of the operating system then what I have. I have OS version 15603.786 but the required version is 17134.0 or higher.

When I go to the check for windows update there is an option to check online for updates from Microsoft update and I have get this update notification "Feature update to Windows 10, version 1903 - Error 0x80242006". When I click retry I get the error in the title: 0x8024a105. How can I fix these errors and update my computer?

I ran the troubleshooter and the only error I got was "windows could not automatically detect this networks proxy settings". this is what it says with the 0x8024a105 error;

"There were some problems installing updates, but we'll try again later. If you keep seeing this and want to search the web or contact support for information, this may help: (0x8024a105)"

any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Try these https://windowsreport.com/windows-could-not-automatically-detect-networks-proxy-settings/

Comment: Usually this denotes a connection issue. Did you restart? Have you tried using a wired/wireless connection instead of the existing internet connection?

Comment: what is the difference in connections?

Comment: when I try to check my proxy settings on inetcpl.cpl its using an automatic configuration script but I can't change it because it says some settings are managed by your organisation.

Comment: Try these https://windowsjet.com/how-to-fix-the-windows-update-error-code-0x8024a105-4041/

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and tried to fix the problem by deleting the catroot2 folder which did not help. Instead I tried a post from the official German Microsoft support:
https://answers.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/forum/all/ich-bekomme-immer-den-fehlercode-0x8024a105-nach/c547c506-5082-4c8a-85cb-a20811957472

In short:

1. Start cmd as admin.
2. Stop all Windows Update related services:

   ```
   net stop wuauserv
   net stop cryptSvc
   net stop bits
   net stop msiserver
   ```
3. Backup the folders `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution`
   and `C:\Windows\System32\catroot2`.
4. Clean the content of `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution` and `C:\Windows\System32\catroot2`. 
   You will need some tries. Sometimes the services restart automatically, so stop them again if the deletion is blocked.
5. Start the services:

   ```
   net start wuauserv
   net start cryptSvc
   net start bits
   net start msiserver
   ```
6. In best case, restart the computer, but in my case I hit update and it took a long time but then it worked.

Answer (score 2):

General Windows Update fixes:

- Run Windows Update Troubleshooter
  This is done in
  *Settings > Update & Security > Troubleshoot > Windows Update > Run the troubleshooter*
- Rename the Update folders by entering the following commands in an elevated
  Command Prompt:

  ```
  net stop wuauserv
  CD %systemroot%\SoftwareDistribution
  Ren Download Download.old
  net start wuauserv
  ```

  Reboot before trying again.
- Check that the BITS service is started
  This is done by running `services.msc`, where the service is named
  "Background Intelligent Transfer Service". Start it manually if it is not started.
- If none of the above have helped,
  force the issue by doing offline upgrade to the latest version.
  For details see the article
  [How to Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).
- If the last step also fails, repeat the installation while booting in Safe mode.

Comment: thankyou so much for the answer but it still doesn't work when I try any of these. The only one I haven't tried probably is safe mode repeating installation however this is because I can't log on when I do safe mode and i have to startup MSConfig on startup and enable them so I can log in. If I hadn't changed the utility manager to a cmd window I would have been screwed.

Comment: If the last step does not work, the only remaining step is a clean install. But before that, try `chkdsk` and `sfc /scannow` to see if they can fix anything.